# Why does tabindex default to -1 on anchor links but not buttons?

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility, language-lawyer

This is more a historical or why question.

Unlike buttons, links tend to have a `tabIndex` of `-1` as default value. I know this is because:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

> If not specified default value is -1

But buttons have a `tabIndex` automatically, so the question is: What was the rationale behind deciding that links shouldn't need to have a `tabIndex` bigger than 0? and because of that the Tab key should ignore the links in a default state.

Comment: I think you have misread the link. No element automatically has a `tabindex` attribute. A `<button>` and an `<a href...>` are automatically in the tab order because they are interactive controls. An author sets `tabindex="-1"` so that it is not in the tab order, but is primed to be added via script.

Comment: the `<a href...>` is not automatically in the tab order, go a do a basic html page put some links and do the test, maybe if the link don't have href is out of the tabindex order?

Comment: I do this all the time. I often put links into demos just so there is another tab stop on the page. Do you have a video of it not working for you? If the link does not have `href` then it is not a link, it is an anchor and does not exist in the tab order.

Comment: @aardrian yeah I think that's why is not working. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML 5.1¹ defines what user agents should do when the [`tabindex` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute) is omitted:

> The user agent should follow platform conventions to determine if the element’s [tabindex focus flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/editing.html#can-be-focused) is set […]

The spec suggests a few elements that should get this flag, including `a` elements (as long as they have an `href` attribute) and `button` elements.

So user agents that follow the spec’s recommendation² don’t make a distinction between `a` and `button` elements with regards to the default focus behaviour.

---

I’m not sure why the linked MDN page contains the quoted statement (it seems to be wrong). Maybe it’s a misunderstanding of what the spec says about the `tabIndex` IDL attribute?

> The `tabIndex` IDL attribute must reflect the value of the `tabindex` content attribute. Its default value is 0 for elements that are focusable and -1 for elements that are not focusable.

---

¹ HTML 5.1 is, as of now, the latest W3C Recommendation. But previous HTML W3C Recommendations and WHATWG’s HTML Living Standard probably don’t define this aspect differently w.r.t. to `a` and `button`.

² It’s not a requirement, as the spec uses *should* instead of *must*.

Answer (score 3):

The MDN page you quote is the definition of the `tabindex` **global attribute** . This does not apply specifically to `button` or links.

In fact, `tabindex` can have four type of values:

- when unset : the element can't be focused programmatically, with the keyboard or with the mouse
- `-1` : the element can be focused programmatically or with the mouse
- `0` : the element can be focused programmatically, with the keyboard or with the mouse
- any value `>0` : do not use this. Never. Not accessible.

The default values for link (`a[href]` and `button`) or other interactive elements (like form fields) is `0`

**The assertion that the default value for any other element is `-1` is false. The default "value" for those other elements is to not define this attribute**